# How do I implement a time picker?

Tags: 7, datetime

I tried to implement a time picker for a field opening hours. I used **Bootstrap Date & Time picker** and I set the **FIELD TYPE** to *date*, but I couldn't see any widget for BDT Picker in widget selection.

Then, I used **jQuery UI Timepicker**. The time picker is showing, but I can select only 0 for hours and 00 for minutes; all other cells are disabled. Also, the default time in the field is the current time.

What could the issue be?

When I select the date field type, the form has a date field with a full calendar. I need a field to pick only the time. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use the [date_popup_timepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_timepicker) module.

Comment: now i used the same ,but the issues i i can't able to hide the date calendar, i need to show only the time field.Is it possible? It is for a field "Opening Hours".

Answer (score 1):

Create a field , select field type as Date (ISO format) or Date. And choose only year, hour, minutes, seconds(if needed). Select Date entry options under MORE SETTINGS AND VALUES , choose custom format as **H:i**

Add time format for H:i and also go-to admin/config/regional/date-time and add date type (to display in node view).
In add/edit page for time picker(only hours)

[image]

In view page

[image]

Hope this helps you with out any help of other modules.

Comment: Thank you @ajay I want a pop up time picker like bootstrap or anything based on jquery.

Comment: You can write custom jQuery popup for particular div/section.
Refer http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/606pgg4o/1/